# How do I save my game with highscores and player positioning in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx, savegame

So I have a game that needs to save high scores for the number of waves, what guns the player has, positioning of the player and the zombies, and so on. I saw something about SharedPreferences but have no clue how to use them. Can someone point me to the right direction or willing to tell me how to use them correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how to save your datas with SharedPreferences :

**Store data**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor spe = settings.edit();
spe.putInt("someKey", someIntegerValue);
spe.putFloat("anotherKey", someFloatValue);
spe.commit();
```

**Retrieve data**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
float floatValue = sp.getFloat("anotherKey", defaultFloatValue);
int intValue = sp.getInt("someKey", defaultIntValue);
```

Where PREFS_NAME is a string containing the name you want for your preference file.

However, SharedPreference is not the only solution, you also can use Internal Storage and SQlite DBs.

Comment: Note that SharedPreferences is Android-only. If you want cross-platform functionality, use LibGDX's Preferences class.

Comment: How do you use the SQlite DB's?

Comment: You should loke there http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db. BTW, I think best solution is using your librairie functions as said Dashto.

Comment: OK thanks, I will look at both but thank you for the link.